# Trying to understand partition by statement

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions

I've seen other posts on SO about getting ones head around partition and order by.  Kinda get it but still a bit confused.

Here is a query provided by my colleague that works:

```
SELECT  EMAIL, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, SOURCE, BILLING_SYSTEM,
        RATE_PLAN, NEXT_CHARGE_DATE, SERVICE_ACTIVATION_DATE, CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE,
        SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE, STATUS, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, PRODUCT_NAME,
        RATE_PLAN_NAME, LOAD_DATE
FROM   theDB
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EMAIL,CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE ) > 1
```

Is this query saying, in plain English, return the fields selected only where the count of records for CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE appear more than once for each EMAIL?

Put another way is it doing this, which does not run (I'm using Teradata and receive error message "Improper use of aggregate function" - when I see that message should I think "use QUALIFY and PARTITION BY?"):

```
SELECT  EMAIL, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, SOURCE, BILLING_SYSTEM,
        RATE_PLAN, NEXT_CHARGE_DATE, SERVICE_ACTIVATION_DATE, CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE,
        SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE, STATUS, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, PRODUCT_NAME,
        RATE_PLAN_NAME, LOAD_DATE
FROM   RDMATBLSANDBOX.TmpNIMSalesForceDB
WHERE COUNT(CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE) >1
GROUP BY EMAIL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite.  Your query, if it ran, would return one row per email (at least it would as MySQL interprets this non-standard syntax).  The original version will return multiple rows for each email.

The equivalent query is essentially:

```
select q.*
from (<your query here>
     ) q join
     (select EMAIL, CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE
      from theDB
      group by EMAIL, CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE
      having count(*) > 1
     ) filter
     on q.email = filter.email and q.CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE = e.CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE;
```

There is a subtle difference, which is usually immaterial.  Your version will recognize `NULL` values in either or both fields.  This version will filter those out, even if there are duplicates.

EDIT:

If you just want the list of emails, use `group by`:

```
select email
from theDB t
where CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE between @start and @end
group by email
having count(*) = 5
```

(or whatever the specific conditions are).

If you need more information about the email or joins, join back to the original tables.

When you are comfortable with this process, you can think about using window/analytic functions to do the same thing.  My concern is that the conditions that you really want may become more complicated and doing the logic in two steps (get the emails, get the additional information) will help you refine it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Gordon Linoff. I'm still a little hazy. I often need to extract data where a count for a particular user (EMAIL) is within a range or a given number.
For example, I want a list of customers (EMAIL) where they have made 5 purchases within a date range. Which of the 3 queries discussed in this post should I resort to for that? If each instance of an email is a sale and CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE is the sales date, what should I do in this situation?

Comment: Think it's clicking now. Using an analytics function like Partition allows me to view counts and other aggregate functions at the individual record level without having to group by.

Comment: @DougFirr . . . That is only part of the fun.  The rest learning about `row_number()`, cumulative aggregations, and using the window options.